# Javascript: SetInterval not repeating style changes

Tags: javascript, html, css, image

As a little break from my rhythm game I've been making with HTML/JavaScript, I decided to make a recreation of the Heatman bossfight from Megaman 2. I'm using `setInterval` to make the code loop infinitely. As a test, I made a function called `moveHeat` which adds 10 Heatman's `left` style value. When I run the `setInterval` with the function, the image (heatman) only moves once. What am I doing wrong?

Here is the code rn:

```js
function moveHeat() {
  document.getElementById("hetman").style.left += "10px";
  return (document.getElementById("hetman").style.left)
}

var heatInterval = setInterval(function() {
  moveHeat()
}, 10);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#hetman {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" id="hetman">
</body>
```

Comment: You’re concatenating the string and actually not incrementing the pixel value of left.

Comment: Yes, you can't add a value with units.

Comment: `"25px" + "10px" = "25px10px"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already stated by someone within the comments, you can not concatenate a string to the `.style.left`. The concatenating as you have it would look like `10px10px10px...`.

So you need a variable that you multiplier that you raise with every interval. That multiplier you sent to your function and multiply it with the 10px.

```js
let i = 1;

function moveHeat(i) {
  document.getElementById("hetman").style.left = `${i * 10}px`;
  return (document.getElementById("hetman").style.left)
}

var heatInterval = setInterval(function() { 
  moveHeat(i);
  i++;
}, 10);
```

```css
*,
*::before,
*::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

#hetman {
  position: relative;
  left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" id="hetman">
</body>
```

Comment: Why no explanation when you post it :/

Comment: @caTS does it really matters?m Sometimes I simply do not have instantly the time to write both at the same time or not the devices to write large chunks of text because I'm at the toilet. Coding on a tablet is one thing, but I really not comfortable writing text there too...

Comment: @tacoshy TMI there...